# C++ weird function overloading between char * and bool

Tags: c++, programming-languages

The following test program has two functions with same name, different param types. I called the function by passing a conditional expression as the param.

> I'm expecting **Write(value ? "yes" : "no")** will call **Write(const
>   string)**, however, it calls **Write(bool).** Why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Write(const string value)
{
  cout << "String" << endl;
}

void Write(bool value)
{
  cout << "Bool" << endl;
}

int main()
{
  bool value = false;

  Write(value ? "yes" : "no");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Side: include `<string>`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the conditional operator; it calls `Write(bool)` if you pass in `"yes"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix your problem by replacing

```
Write(value ? "yes" : "no");
```

by

```
Write(string(value ? "yes" : "no"));
```

The problem is as follows: you didn't define a function which takes a `char*` as a paramater and because of this an implicit conversion must be made. However, the implicit conversion is made to `bool` rather than `std::string` because `bool` is a built-in type.